# Utilizing all CPU on Google Cloud Compute Engine V;

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, cpu

I bought access to a Machine type e2-highmem-16 (16 vCPUs, 128 GB memory) on Google Cloud because I need to run a lot of computationally expensive code.

I used ssh from my Mac and installed python with conda and all the packages I need and I can run the code. The only problem is that the code almost runs slower on the VM than it does on my computer. According to the Compute Engine Statistics I've only utilized 0.03% of the CPU. Is this why it is so slow? If So How do I make use of 100% CPU?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your code.  Fair chance that your code is not optimized for parallel computations and is using 1 of your 16 cores however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt attach the **CODE**, but, assuming you have one main function that runs all the calculations for you and it looks like this (enogh generic so you can pass to it via *args and **kwargs what ever you like):

```
def f_execute_work(*args, **kwargs):
    .....
    .....
```

you can use concurrent.future module for paralel execution. it will get the work for you:

The concurrent.futures module provides a high-level interface for asynchronously executing callables.

The asynchronous execution can be performed with threads, using ThreadPoolExecutor, or separate processes, using ProcessPoolExecutor. Both implement the same interface, which is defined by the abstract Executor class.

```
import concurrent.futures
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=psutil.cpu_count()) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(f_execute_work, *args, **kwargs)
    print(future.result())
```

**`submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)`** Schedules the callable, fn, to be executed as fn(*args **kwargs) and returns a Future object representing the execution of the callable.

use the psutil.cpu_count() to get the logical cores number for dispatching maximum workers and utilizing cpu cores.

Comment: @TeodorFredriksson - my pleasure. please vote the answer up (push the up arrow) thanks for accepting it. glad to help you.

Comment: Follow up question! I first run a shorter code that managed to get about 80% CPU, Now im running something long but it now ossiclates between 20%-60% Can I set minimum workers too?